# In Swagger, what is the responses looks like if I define the response object like this

Tags: swagger

I want this API to produce JSON in response HTTP body.

```
 responses:
        '200':
          description: success
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Company'
        '400':
          description: client doesn't exist
 definitions:
   Company:
    description: ''
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
        description: Empty when creating a record
      name:
        type: string
        description: Not empty when creating record, or updating this field
      email: 
        type: string
```

I think the response body would be:

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "company": {...company object...}
}
```

Is this correct? or

```
{
  "200": {...company object...}
}
```

Here is the document that swagger tool generated:

[image]

Comment: How about you try and let us know?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Swagger is for generating API document, I tried and update my question with a picture. I am not very clear what the response object structure is. I may not understand swagger definition object right.

Comment: How do I find the definition yaml for this API?  http://petstore.swagger.io/#/